# Formatting individual characters in a cell in Excel using office-js

Tags: javascript, excel, office-js

I would like to format individual characters inside an Excel cell using Office js. Specifically I would like to be able to highlight and color certain letters in a string inside a cell. I am using a Vue taskpane.

What I want: [image: Single Formatted Letter]

What I get: [image: Formatted Cell]

So far I have only found ways of formatting entire cells rather than single letters inside a cell.

```
window.Excel.run(async (context) => {
  var range = context.workbook.getSelectedRange()
  range.format.fill.color = 'green'
  await context.sync()
})
```

Something like this will only ever format the entire cell because the smallest range unit is a cell

Comment: Can I get some feedback on why this question shows little research or is unclear?

Comment: Can you share the code you are currently using, or what you have attempted so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We did some investigation for implementing this API last year, However, this API was postponed, the main reason is that the Excel Online and iOS is not yet supported this feature. Would you please share us your scenarios? help us understand how important this API you need?

Comment: I work for a biotech company and highlighting individual characters would be extremely useful in identifying mutations in sequences. It would also be used for showing alignments and identifying regions in a protein

Comment: Got it, thanks for your comments to let us know the scenario, I have communicate with Excel Online team, they will put this work item in their backlog, we will keep tracking their status and we will implement this API after this feature is done

Comment: I'm having the same issue. I need to write text on a cell where one word is colored differently. Is there a solution to this problem yet?

Comment: I'm also interested, is there any update on this? Thanks!

Comment: it seems it is supported in Excel online, it would be great if you could submit a request in Uservoice and upvote your request.

Comment: Two years later and no progress? Disappointing and demotivating. I keep delaying the implementation of my add in fort text diff in Excel because of this.